# What the relationship of font size between PIL.ImageFont.truetype and tkinter font?

Tags: python, tkinter, fonts, python-imaging-library

It looks like that I use the same font and size in `ImageFont.truetype` as set in tkinter, but get different size.

Following code show the difference, first button created by text with option `font`, next two buttons created by image which the text is drawn by PIL.ImageDraw with PIL.ImageFont.

```py
import io
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageTk, ImageFont

font_tk = ("Courier New", 20)
font_pil = ImageFont.truetype(font='cour.ttf', size=20)

root = tk.Tk()

btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="Button", font=font_tk)
btn1.pack()



im = Image.new("RGBA", (200, 200), (0, 0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.text((0, 100), "Button", font=font_pil, fill='black')
im = im.crop(im.getbbox())

image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
btn2 = tk.Button(root, image=image1)
btn2.pack()

buffer = io.BytesIO()
im.save(buffer, format="PNG")
data = buffer.getvalue()
image2 = tk.PhotoImage(data=data)
btn3 = tk.Button(root, image=image2)
btn3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image]

How can I get the right font size in image as the font size option in tk.Button ?

Comment: You can use negative size on tkinter font, then the size will be in pixels.

Comment: In https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageFont.html, it say parameter: size – The requested size, in points ? Can it be in points if the description is wrong ?

Comment: I think the  *points* in Pillow doc means *pixels*.

Comment: OK, Thank you for the reply and it work well.

Comment: You can use `root.call('tk', 'scaling')` to get the current scaling factor, then multiply this factor to the font size (need to round it to integer) on `Pillow`.

Comment: Yes, set the size as `int(50*scale+0.5)` in `ImageFont.truetype`, it work. Thank you again !

Comment: Pillow documentation has since been corrected, it now says pixels: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/ImageFont.html#PIL.ImageFont.truetype